# Is it good practice to have multiple data contexts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When breaking a solution out into multiple projects, does it make sense to have multiple data contexts or share the context?

Example, for a web portal you have:

```
App.Service1
App.Service2
App.Web (references Service1 and Service2)
```

Now would you have it so that Service1 and Service2 share the same DataContext or they each have their own?

Keep in mind that both `Service1` and `Service2` are both connecting to the exact same database, they are just seperated in order to keep things more isolated.

I'm using EF6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to share the same context. Multiple contexts make sense when you are aggregating data from different databases.

Comment: SO to share, I would either pass in the context to the Service's contructor or property, or use IOC then correct?  But doesn't that mean the context then has have the configurations setup also?  If they are in separate projects, how will this work?

Comment: In order to instantiate your context all you need is a connection string that will live in your web.config file. So basically it's the work of your DI framework to inject the context into the DAL layer.

Comment: I thought you have to set all the entities the context will handle first in the class that inherits from DbContex. Meaning you have to pass around a context to each service, but that context has to be aware of all the Entities/Models.

Comment: Yes, you could have a single DbContext instance that will have all your entities as DbSet properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a single context mainly as it will stop Entity Framework for getting confused with Migrations or Schema change detection if two contexts live on the same database

If separation is a concern and your design allows for it, I would make the context implement two interfaces which is the logical split of Service1 and Service2 and use the interfaces throughout your code.

It is also worth noting you can can't have cross context relationships in regards to navigation properties but that doesn't sound like an issue in your case

Answer (score 1):

In general I would recomment you to use one Context for simplicity, **but** íf your Data Model (Context) is very large than you will maybe have a better performance if you use more than one Context. But it makes only sense if your entities don't have a relation. And it can be difficult to handle many contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I personally see no use of having two data contexts with the same database. I see your idea to  isolate things but I think EF is powerful enough not to do that this way. I use two contexts for different databases as @Darin said.